# Meteor publish-composite and nested collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to build an app that has a many to many relationship in Meteor. There will be jobs, clients and users collections. Clients can have multiple jobs, and most importantly multiple users can work on the same job.

I have the jobs collection set up as follows in my fixtures file:

```
Jobs.insert({
  jobNum: 'Somejob',
  clientId: 'XXXXXXXX',
  clientName: 'Some Client',
  rate: XX,
  userNames: [
    {userId: user1._id},
    {userId: user2._id}
  ],
  active: true
});
```

I am publishing according to the readme for publish-composite, but I cannot get the users to publish to the client. Here is the publication code:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('jobsActive', {
  find: function() {
  // Find all active jobs any client
  return Jobs.find({active: true});
  },

  children: [
    {
     find: function (job) {
        // Return a client associated with the job
        return Clients.find({_id: job.clientId}); 
    }
    },
    {
     find: function (job) {
        // Return all users associated with the job
        // This is where the problem is
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: job.userNames.userId});
     }
   }
 ]
});
```

I can't figure out how to correctly find over an array. I tried a number of things and nothing worked. Is this possible? Or do I need to go about this in another way? I've thought about referencing jobs in the users collection, but there will be far more jobs than users, so it seems to make more sense like this.

BTW, I did subscribe to 'jobsActive' as well. The other two collections are coming over to the client side fine; I just can't get the users collection to publish.

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`job.userNames.userId` doesn't exist in your collection. `job.userNames` is an array of objects which have the key `userId`.

Try something like `_.map( job.userNames, function( users ){ return users.userId } )`.

Your code will be:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('jobsActive', {
    find: function() {
        return Jobs.find({active: true});
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function (job) {
                return Clients.find({_id: job.clientId}); 
            }
        },
        {
            find: function (job) {
                return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $in: _.map( job.userNames, function( users ) { return users.userId } ) } });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This certainly makes more sense but it doesn't work either. When I run User.find().count() on the console I still get 0. I do get the right number for Jobs and Clients so the subscribe is working. I do have the underscore package loaded, too. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can't edit above, but I am running **Meteor.users.find().count()** on the console and getting 0.

Comment: What are you getting when you run `Jobs.find({}, { fields: { userNames: 1 } })` Could you paste it here?

Comment: I added .fetch() to what you asked for. I get two objects. One has an array of 2 userIds and one has an array of 1.

`Object
_id: "wQ2tGiLTqyRiZrnZN"
userNames: Array[2]
0: Object
userId: "1"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
userId: "2"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object`

`Object
_id: "xMWHp8NRMCsp5YGYz"
userNames: Array[1]
0: Object
userId: "2"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Are those user ids actual id's of existing users? 
The `userId` has the value, "2", is there an user in the DB with _id = 2?

Comment: Yes. The fixture for the users goes like this:

`if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0){
  var jeffId = Meteor.users.insert({
    _id: '1',
    profile: {name: 'Jeff'}
  });
  var jeff = Meteor.users.findOne(jeffId);

  var amberId = Meteor.users.insert({
    _id: '2',
    profile: {name: 'Amber'}
  })
  var amber = Meteor.users.findOne(amberId);
}`

Then I used the jeff and amber variables later to populate userNames: {userId: amber._id}

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need publish-composite at all, try this code snippet. It works for me!

```
Meteor.publish('jobsActive', function () {
    return Events.find(
    {
        $or: [
            // { public: { $eq: true } },
            { active: true },
            { userNames: this.userId}
        ],
    },
    {
        sort: {createdAt: -1}
    }
    );
});
```